# AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`COMPANY`' given input columns: [spark_catalog.default.companies.value]

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I got this error while doing sparksql

```
val 
df1=spark.read.format("csv").option("inferSchema",true).option("header",true).load("/FileStore/tables/dataset.csv");
    df1.createOrReplaceTempView("companies")

val result2 = sqlContext.sql("select BRANCH from companies where COMPANY =infosys  ");
result2.show();
```

> AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`COMPANY`' given input columns:
> [spark_catalog.default.companies.value]; line 1 pos 35; 'Project
> ['BRANCH]
> +- 'Filter ('COMPANY = 'infosys)
> +- SubqueryAlias spark_catalog.default.companies   +- Relation[value#79] parquet

Comment: Sounds like you don't have a column called COMPANY in your CSV file.

Comment: Can you run df1.printSchema() to make sure that you have a column called COMPANY in your DF?